# Grep for a token outside of the last line

Tags: grep

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't get the right syntax. I'm trying to use grep to find all files with a certain token that have at least one line following the line with the token in it. So something like:

```
blah blah token blah
another line here
```

would be found by the grep, but not:

```
blah blah token blah
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `grep` doesn't do multi-line stuff like this (though there is a -A option to print trailing context). One way would be to use `head` to cut off the last line first, then pipe it to `grep`:

```
for f in *; do
    echo "$f:"
    head -n -1 "$f" | grep token
```

Above code is not tested, I'm stuck on Windows atm.